# static setter method injection in Spring

Tags: java, spring, static

I have following requirement
I wanted to pass `http:\\localhost:9080\testws.cls`  value as setter injection through spring configuration file. How can i do this static variable setter injection for `TEST1_WSDL_LOCATION`

```
public class test1
    extends javax.xml.ws.Service
{

    private final static URL TEST1_WSDL_LOCATION;

    static {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http:\\localhost:9080\testws.cls");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        TEST1_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }

    public test1(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public test1() {
        super(TEST1_WSDL_LOCATION, new QName("http://tempuri.org", "test1"));
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     returns test1Soap
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "test1Soap")
    public Code1Soap getTest1Soap() {
        return (Test1Soap)super.getPort(new QName("http://tempuri.org", "Test1Soap"), Test1Soap.class);
    }

}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: What's the point of making it static? Just make it an instance variable of an object with singleton scope and inject into it the usual way.

Comment: Working solution is already discussed in another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763279/injecting-values-for-static-constants-in-spring. Also check http://www.connorgarvey.com/blog/?p=105. Worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way for Spring to initialize a static final field from the outside.

It just wouldn't be possible. Static final fields are initialized at class load time, long before Spring has the chance to do anything (and you can't pass parameters to the ClassLoader anyway).

You will have to re-think your design. This can't work!

Comment: Thank you.This is generated class for client webservice. I want to pass WSDL url value from configuration as this value varies from Dev to production. What do you suggest for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a setter on a bean instance do it.

```
Class WsdlCode{   
private static URL WSDL_LOCATION;
    public void setUrlString(String url) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }
```

Of course, the field won't be available till after all of the beans have had their properties set, but Spring has some interfaces for that. [`InitializingBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) for example.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my post to have complete code. So this url should available for constructior. Can i do for the same?

Comment: @vishnu: That's more complex. I'd suggest moving the WSDL_LOCATION to some sort of global bean rather than leaving it a static field. Or you could just make the Code1() constructor take a single string with the WSDL url.

Comment: We can't do static setter method injection, i can't use Code1() constructor as it is giving error as this class is inherited by Service class. So i need go for this global bean? How to do this. It is very baic. Thank you for ur time

Answer (score 1):

```
@Component
public class UserUtils
{
    private static UserAccessor userAccessor;

    /**
     * Sets the user DAO. This method should never be called except by Spring
     * @param userAccessor The user accessor to set
     */
    @Autowired(required = true)
    public void setUserAccessor(userAccessor UserAccessor) {
        UserUtils.userAccessor = userAccessor;
    }
}
```

resources:http://www.connorgarvey.com/blog/?p=105#codesyntax_1

Answer (score 0):

As someone has already mentioned, Spring doesn't work that way. A static initializer would be run before Spring could affect the value.

What you probably should do is instantiate your Code1 class in Spring as a bean and set the value there. If the value needs to be shared by multiple instances of your bean, then make the value a singleton scoped bean in Spring.